# SQL - Iterate through list of Local Tables with same schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a number of local databases on my server: NYNYL, CALIL, FLJXL. Each of them are copies of the exact same schema with different data.

I'd like to build a query which iterates through a list of these local databases, grabs data from each and unions them all.

```
SELECT  
    'NYNY' as ItemSource,
    NYNYL.dbo.[NYNY INVOITEM].itemid, 
    NYNYL.dbo.[NYNY INVOITEM].price                      
FROM            
    NYNYL.dbo.[NYNY INVOITEM]

UNION ALL

SELECT  
    'CALI' as ItemSource,
    CALIL.dbo.[CALI INVOITEM].itemid, 
    CALIL.dbo.[CALI INVOITEM].price                      
FROM            
    CALIL.dbo.[CALI INVOITEM]

UNION ALL
ETC ETC ETC
```

In the above example, instead of 'NYNY' and 'CALI', I'd use some variable which holds those names as a list and iterates through them.

Possible? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: SQL Server does not support macro substitution.  That leaves Dynamic SQL

Comment: Most of the time when I see this type of design it can be fixed by using a single table and adding one additional column to indicate the source. Having multiple copies of the same table where the name of the table indicates some piece of data is a poor design choice.

Comment: @SeanLange These are copies of local software installs; I don't have the ability to change the setup

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Ahh gotcha. You could create a view if you have a static number of tables. Or dynamic sql as John said.

Comment: this article can help you [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the `Dynamic SQL` to generate `Select` Statement for Specific `Table` :

```
DECLARE @BaseDatabaseName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ApartmentManagementSystem' -->> variable to hold base Database name
DECLARE @BaseTableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'User' -->> Variable to hold table name, can be used as stored procedure parameter


DECLARE @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

Set @SQL = CONCAT('Select * From ', @BaseDatabaseName, '.dbo.', QUOTENAME(@BaseTableName))

DECLARE DatabaseList CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [name]
FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb') and [name] <> @BaseDatabaseName
OPEN DatabaseList;
FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseList INTO @DatabaseName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        Set @SQL += CONCAT(' Union All ', 'Select * From ', @DatabaseName, '.dbo.', QUOTENAME(@BaseTableName))
    FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseList INTO @DatabaseName;
    END;
CLOSE DatabaseList;
DEALLOCATE DatabaseList;

PRINT @SQL
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```